# What is the maximal delay between the publication of an investigation report recomending a study and the beginning of this study?

Tags: easa-regulations, accident-investigation

This question is focused on EASA regulations, mainly because the question arise when reading an investigation report written by the BEA.

Investigation reports results in lots of recommendations to improve safety. Some recommendations involve certification process and are then implemented when certifying new aircraft types, other involve training process and are then implemented by modifying training, other recommend studies. 
For example, if I take the [AF447 final report](http://bea.aero/docspa/2009/f-cp090601.en/pdf/f-cp090601.en.pdf), the section 4.3.7 recommends that:

> EASA study the relevance of having a dedicated warning [...]

This is not the only study recommended by this report, this is just an example.
On another report named [Study on aeroplane state awareness during go-around](https://www.bea.aero/fileadmin/documents/etudes/asaga/asaga.study.pdf) (2013) (which proves by its title that studies are conducted), the section 8.2 recommends that:

> Manufacturers study the feasibility of simplifying the management of the aircraft reconfiguration [...]

Then I imagined this lead to other studies.

In short, reports by investigation entities (NTSB, BEA,...) may recommend studies to be conducted. This leads to other reports, possibly asking for other studies to be conducted. It looks like an endless, yet useful, process.

Are those recommended studies always conducted (maybe this is ensured by an EASA regulation I'm not aware of)? If so, is there a maximal delay after the publication of the recommendation to start the study? Are studies recommended by different types of publication (accident reports, studies report,...) treated differently in respect to those delays?

Comment: I can't say with certainty about EASA, but generally these are just recommendations and thus are non-binding.